# Sending whatsapp messages via python/JS

Tags: javascript, python, whatsapp

I made a program which takes information from excel and sends messages via python.
I used selenium and "span" for finding the element I need.

**now, WhatsApp changed their HTML and there is no span anymore.**

the old code is here:

```
import time
import xlrd

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_binary = "D:\pycharm\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary)

driver.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')

file_location = "C:\Users\ErelNahum\Desktop\data.xlsx"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
print "there is " + str(book.nsheets) + " sheets"
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
cols = sheet.ncols - 1
print "the number of cols is " + str(cols)


raw_input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')


for i in range(cols):
    tel = sheet.cell_value((i+1), 0)
    tel = tel.replace("\"", "")
    print tel
    messege = sheet.cell_value((i+1), 1)
    messege = (messege +str(b+1))

    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(tel))
    user.click()

    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_input-container')


    msg_box.send_keys(messege)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('compose-btn-send').click()

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

**if you have any idea how to change the program so it will work please show me.
I know Python, JS, C# so every language is fine.**

Thank You,
Erel.

Comment: SO is not a coding service

Comment: "via python/JS", then why did you tag [tag:c#]? Also, nobody will do your job for free here. Please read [ask]

Comment: I didnt ask you to write my code.. 
i asked if you have an idea for replacement for "spans" in the HTML.

Comment: @Erel Nahum, What happens when a number from excel sheet is unknown and not saved in contacts as a contact by a whatsapp user... Does it opens chat window for such number too..?

Answer (score 0):

Check whatever tag surrounds the data you're trying to scrap after the span tag was removed, and adjust the code accordingly.

There is no general replacement for span. Can you provide the markup you're trying to scrap (at least the part where the span tag was)

Comment: there is only div(s)..
       " msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
        [@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]')"
that doesnt work

Comment: what about the div class "_39LWd" did you try to reference to this ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element